# Azure Alert when a user is added or removed from Azure Active Directory Group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-alerts

I'm trying to create an Azure Alert to notify me when someone adds a user to an Azure Active Directory Group. I found the query below but its not working

```
SecurityEvent
 | where EventID in (4728, 4729, 4732, 4733, 4756, 4757) and TargetAccount contains 
 "Admin" 
and TimeGenerated > ago(24h)
 | summarize AggregatedValue = count() by TargetAccount
 | order by AggregatedValue desc
```

Comment: Can you share the error you're getting? Also where are you trying to configure this alert, Log Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to create an Azure Alert to notify me when someone adds a user to an Azure Active Directory Group.

I have used below **KQL** query to check the **Azure AD** group activity logs.

```
AuditLogs
| where OperationName contains "Add member to group"
| where TargetResources contains "newgrp"
| extend prop = parse_json(InitiatedBy)
| extend InitialedBy=prop.user.userPrincipalName
|project InitialedBy , TimeGenerated,OperationName,Category,InitiatedBy,Result,ActivityDisplayName
```

**Output**

[image]

If you want to check removed users from **Azure AD Group**, use below query.

```
AuditLogs
| where Category contains_cs "GroupManagement"
| where OperationName contains "Remove member from group"
| where TargetResources contains "newgrp"
| extend prop = parse_json(InitiatedBy)
| extend InitialedBy=prop.user.userPrincipalName
|project InitialedBy , TimeGenerated,OperationName,Category,InitiatedBy,Result,ActivityDisplayName
```

**Output:**

[image]

Create an alert by clicking **New alert rule**

[image]

Create an **Action Group** to trigger the email.

[image]

Once you add the user to the **Azure AD Group**, you will get the alert as below.

**Alert triggered in portal**

[image]

**Received email**

[image]